# Reference text color in conditionall formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

What we are trying to accomplish is to reference text color in conditionally formatted cells that meet a certain metric. We have a for loop that checks the text color of each cell going down a row.

Colored cells done via conditional formatting can't be referenced via font.color as manually/VBA colored cells are (as far as I know), so we are looking for a way to reference the conditionally formatted color/look in the formatting function and grab the color.

```
Dim rstarpos As Long
Dim cstartpos1 As Long

rstartpos = 9
cstartpos1 = 3

For i = rstartpos To 10
Sheets("Scorecard").Select
Cells(i, cstartpos1).Select
MsgBox Cells(i, cstartpos1).Font.Color
```

Font.color would ideally report what the font color of the cell in the loop is. However, because of the conditional formatting it's not. Is there a way to call the conditionally formatted cell's color?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2010, you can use the DisplayFormat property of a range to get its *displayed* format, including the effects of conditional formatting (and table styles).  In your example, the last line would change to:

`MsgBox Cells(i, cstartpos1).DisplayFormat.Font.Color`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what we needed and couldn't find. You rock!